# Vertex-Animation in javascript for A-Frame

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe, vertex-shader

Is there anything like a formula-deformer animation for A-Frame? The Idea is that I have a geometry in A-Frame and a js-script which makes the geometry wobbble. I tried the noise-shader from the A-Frame-Extras but it breaks the vertexes and doesn`t look good and I`m not a good coder to do it myself!

I`m happy about any ideas! Cheers, Can

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler example that might help https://glitch.com/edit/#!/equinox-rainstorm?path=shaders/grass-vertex.glsl:9:5

Basically using a vertex shader to bend the top half of the mesh.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good but I guess it doesn`t work for me because I also need to load a texture on my geometry. Maybe there is a way to animate the polygons and have a standard shader?

Comment: Or it would be thinkable to add a src to the noise shader!

Comment: Yes it is possible, instead of using an absolute color value like here you would use the color in the right position on your texture (cf UV mapping).

Comment: Note that you can also modify the position of the vertex in threejs if you are more familiar with it.